# Testing memory bandwidth - Odd results

Tags: memory, assembly, benchmarking, bandwidth

Hy everyone,

Was asking myself the other day how much different access patterns affected memory read speed (mostly thinking about the frequency vs bus size discussion, and the impact of cache hit rate), so made a small program to test memory speed doing sequential and fully random accesses, but the results I got are quite odd, so I'm not trusting my code.

My idea was quite straightforward, just loop on an array and mov the data to a register. Made 3 versions, one moves 128 bits at a time with sse, the other 32 , and the last one 32 again but doing two movs, the first one loading a random number from an array, and the second one reading from the position specified by the prev value.

I got ~40 GB/s for the sse version, that it's reasonable considering i'm using an i7 4790K with DDR3 1600 cl9 memory at dual channel, that gives about 25 GB/s, so add to that cache and it feels ok, but then I got 3.3 GB/s for the normal sequential, and the worst, 15 GB/s for the random one. That last result makes me think that the bench is bogus.

Below is the code, if anyone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated. Did the inner loop in assembly to make sure it only did a mov.

EDIT: Managed to get a bit more performance by using vlddqu ymm0, buffL[esi] (avx) instead of movlps, went from 38 GB/s to 41 GB/s

EDIT 2: Did some more testing, unrolling the inner assembly loop, making a version that loads 4 times per iteration and another one that loads 8 times. Got ~35 GB/s for the x4 version and ~24 GB/s for the x8 version

```
#define PASSES 1000000

double bw = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Running : ";

    bw = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < PASSES;n++)
    {
        if(n % 100000 == 0) cout << ".";
        const int l = 1 << 16;
        int buffL[l];

        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;        // ticks per second
        LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;           // ticks

        // get ticks per second
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

        // start timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

        int maxByte = l*4;
        __asm
        {
            push esi

            mov esi,0

            loopL0:
                movlps xmm0, buffL[esi]
                add esi,16
                cmp esi,maxByte
                jb loopL0

            pop esi
        }

        // stop timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        // compute elapsed time in millisec
        double ms = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;

        bw += (double(4ull*l)/1073741824.0) / (double(ms)*0.001);
    }
    bw /= double(PASSES);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "   Sequential (SSE) : " << bw << " GB/s " << endl;

    cout << "Running : ";
    bw = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < PASSES;n++)
    {
        if(n % 100000 == 0) cout << ".";
        const int l = 1 << 16;
        int buffL[l];

        for(int t = 0;t < l;t++) buffL[t] = (t+1)*4;

        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;        // ticks per second
        LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;           // ticks

        // get ticks per second
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

        // start timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

        int maxByte = l*4;
        __asm
        {
            push esi

            mov esi,0

            loopL1:
                mov esi, buffL[esi]
                cmp esi,maxByte
                jb loopL1

            pop esi
        }

        // stop timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        // compute elapsed time in millisec
        double ms = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;

        bw += (double(4ull*l)/1073741824.0) / (double(ms)*0.001);
    }
    bw /= double(PASSES);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "   Sequential : " << bw << " GB/s " << endl;

    cout << "Running : ";

    bw = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < PASSES;n++)
    {
        if(n % 100000 == 0) cout << ".";
        const int l = 1 << 14;
        int buffL[l];

        int maxByte = l*4;

        int roffset[l];
        for(int t = 0;t < l;t++) roffset[t] = (rand()*4) % maxByte;

        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;        // ticks per second
        LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;           // ticks

        // get ticks per second
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

        // start timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

        __asm
        {
            push esi
            push edi

            mov esi,0

            loopL2:
                mov edi, roffset[esi]
                mov edi, buffL[edi]
                add esi,4
                cmp esi,maxByte
                jb loopL2

            pop edi
            pop esi
        }

        // stop timer
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        // compute elapsed time in millisec
        double ms = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;

        bw += (double(2*4ull*l)/1073741824.0) / (double(ms)*0.001);
    }
    bw /= double(PASSES);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "   Random : " << bw << " GB/s " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid the possibility of one test influencing the outcome of another because of either compiler optimization or the cache, separate each of your three tests loops into their own source file.  (So that each gets compiled seperately).   Then a another source file that implements "main" and takes a command line argument of which test to run.  Run the tests separately and run multiple times.

Comment: Declare maxByte as const.  `const int maxByte = l*4;`

Answer (score 1):

Gathering the measurement code into a Bandwidth class, creating some constants, having all three tests use the same buffer (and size) aligning the tops of the loops and computing random offset into the entire buffer (3rd test):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t passes = 1000000;
constexpr size_t buffsize = 64 * 1024;
constexpr double gigabyte = 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0;
constexpr double gb_per_test = double(long long(buffsize) * passes) / gigabyte;

struct Bandwidth
{
    LARGE_INTEGER pc_tick_per_sec;
    LARGE_INTEGER start_pc;
    const char* _label;
public:
    Bandwidth(const char* label): _label(label) 
    {
        cout << "Running : ";
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&pc_tick_per_sec); 
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_pc); 
    }

    ~Bandwidth() {
        LARGE_INTEGER end_pc{};           
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_pc); 
        const auto seconds = double(end_pc.QuadPart - start_pc.QuadPart) / pc_tick_per_sec.QuadPart;
        cout << "\n   " << _label << ": " << gb_per_test / seconds << " GB/s " << endl;
    }
};

int wmain()
{
    vector<char> buff(buffsize, 0);
    const auto buff_begin = buff.data();
    const auto buff_end = buff.data()+buffsize;

    {
        Bandwidth b("Sequential (SSE)");

        for (size_t n = 0; n < passes; ++n) {
            __asm {
                push esi
                push edi
                mov esi, buff_begin
                mov edi, buff_end

                align 16
            loopL0:
                movlps xmm0, [esi]
                lea esi, [esi + 16]
                cmp esi, edi
                jne loopL0

                pop edi
                pop esi
            }
        }
    }

    {
        Bandwidth b("Sequential (DWORD)");
        for (int n = 0; n < passes; ++n) {
            __asm {
                push esi
                push edi
                mov esi, buff
                mov edi, buff_end
                align 16
                loopL1:
                mov eax, [esi]
                lea esi, [esi + 4]
                cmp esi, edi
                jne loopL1

                pop edi
                pop esi
            }
        }
    }

    {
        uint32_t* roffset[buffsize];
        for (auto& roff : roffset)
            roff = (uint32_t*)(buff.data())+(uint32_t)(double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (buffsize / sizeof(int)));
        const auto roffset_end = end(roffset);
        Bandwidth b("Random");

        for (int n = 0; n < passes; ++n) {
            __asm {
                push esi
                push edi
                push ebx
                lea edi, roffset        //begin(roffset)
                mov ebx, roffset_end    //end(roffset)

                align 16
                loopL2:
                mov esi, [edi]   //fetch the next random offset
                mov eax, [esi]   //read from the random location
                lea edi, [edi + 4]  // point to the next random offset
                cmp edi, ebx    //are we done?
                jne loopL2

                pop ebx
                pop edi
                pop esi
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also found more consistent results if I `SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);` and `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);`

Answer (score 0):

Your second test has one array on the stack that is `1 << 16` in size.  That's 64k.  Or more easier to read:

```
int buffL[65536];
```

Your third test has two arrays on the stack.  Both at `1 << 14' in size. That's 16K each

```
int buffL[16384];
int roffset[16384];
```

So right away you are using a much smaller stack size (i.e. fewer pages being cached and swapped out). I think your loop is only iterating half as many times in the third test as it is in the second.  Maybe you meant to declare `1 << 15` (or `1 << 16`) as the size instead for each array instead?